# How to install gtk3 in CentOS?

Tags: centos, package-management, chrome, gtk, gtk3

I have `gtk2` installed on my `ec2 machine` instance. In order to install the latest `google-chrome`/`mozilla-firefox` version, it requires `libgtk3` to be installed in the machine

> - Will there be any issues if I upgrade the version to gtk3?
> - What is the actual cmd to install gtk3 in centOS Linux?

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx bin]$ sudo yum update google-chrome-stable
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
3615 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:57.0.2987.133-1 will be updated
---> Package google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:64.0.3282.167-1 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libgtk-3.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-64.0.3282.167-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-64.0.3282.167-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgdk-3.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-64.0.3282.167-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-64.0.3282.167-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libgtk-3.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-64.0.3282.167-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-64.0.3282.167-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libgdk-3.so.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

---

The below terminal cmd helped me install the latest `google-chrome` browser; however, it would be great if someone gives the apt answer for this question

```
curl https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash
```

Answer (score 4):

Following command worked for me:

```
sudo yum install gtk3-devel
```

Kindly note that I was using Python 3.6.3.

Comment: The question is about gtk3 library, not development headers (gtk3-devel). How is Python relevant here?